# simple drag pictures onto browser plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Looking for something like this: http://min.us - where user can easily drag'n'drop images onto the page, and there is a listener that takes them, does something with them (uploads to server).

Does there exist an easy jquery plugin for that?  Or is this way complicated??  Thanks!

Maybe HTML5 has a drag'n'drop listening mechanism??

Answer (score 1):

[**Look at the HTML5 File API**](http://html5demos.com/file-api) — there are tons of tutorials on the net already. Take a look at [this demo](http://html5demos.com/file-api) + source.

Answer (score 0):

The plupload plugin that the site 'min.us' you referenced is available http://www.plupload.com/

But Internet Explorer does not support Drag into browser.